# CefSharp : How to handle the Cefsharp download on Read Only directory where we do not have write permission

Tags: c#, cefsharp

How to handle the `Cefsharp` download on Read Only directory where we do not have write permission.

I have created a folder with no write permission and trying to download a file.

Its not throwing any exception. How to handle or catch this one?

OnBeforeDownload:

```cs
if(folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (callback)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
                                , downloadItem.SuggestedFileName);
        var size = downloadItem.TotalBytes;
        callback.Continue(path, showDialog: false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so you have a folder where you cannot write to and you still want to save something there? Or do I get this wrong (then assuming others will get this wrong also)?

Comment: Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3702 please just ask your question once and wait for a response.